# Make matrix from shifted vector matlab vectorization

Tags: matlab, vector, matrix, vectorization

Geetings, here's the little problem.

I have a vector v (size(v) = T), a positive number P, P < T nad positive number N, N < T. And want to make matrix M with size PxN, so that:

```
M = [v(T),     v(T-1), ....., v(T-N+2),   v(T-N+1);
     v(T-1),   v(T-2), ....., v(T-N+1),   v(T-N)  ;
     v(T-2),   v(T-3), ....., v(T-N),     v(T-N-1);
        .        .       .       .           .    ;
        .        .       .       .           .    ;
     v(T-P+1), v(T-P), ....., v(T-P-N+3), v(T-P-N+2)]
```

It holds that T > P + N.

Let given an example.

```
v = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]';
P = 3;
N = 3;
M = [5, 4, 3;
     4, 3, 2;
     3, 2, 1]
```

I know how to do this using for loop, but I also think that it is possible do by vectorizations - here the problem is - I am not so skilled in vectorizations.

Thx for hints and so on :))

Comment: Please post your loop code

Comment: Also does in your example you'll have `v(T-P-N)` in the bottom right which is `v(5-3-3)` which is `v(-1)` which is undefined. Please fix your constraints. I'm assuming P + N < T

Comment: Sory, I saw the fault just after posting the answer.

Comment: It's still wrong. For example `P=4` and `N=4` are valid according to your constraints. But they won't work.

Comment: Assuming which T? There is T > P + N.

Answer (score 7):

Use the [Hankel](http://www.mathworks.ch/ch/help/matlab/ref/hankel.html) matrix:

```
v = [1 2 3 4 5];
T = length(v);
P = 3;
N = 3;
out = hankel(v(T:-1:T-P+1),v(T-P+1:-1:T-P-N+2));
```

Answer (score 3):

You can make use of [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html)

```
v = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]';
P = 3;
N = 3;
idx = bsxfun(@minus, length(v):-1:length(v)-N+1, (0:P-1)');

result  = v(idx);
```

this will result in

```
result =

     5     4     3
     4     3     2
     3     2     1
```